# Raven's Inception

Tags: logical-deduction, visual

**Raven's Inception**

Fluff (no clues):

> The horde is chasing you. You run for your life along the main
>   street of a small nondescript town you wish you had never set foot in.
>   You turn a hard right, put your entire body behind you and crash into
>   the door of a building. You burst into a small office in a explosion
>   of wooden splinters. Disoriented and with pain throbbing everywhere
>   you look around. An ominous staircase leads to a row of heavy ornate
>   doors numbered 1 to 4.
>
> At the bottom of the staircase sits Leonardo DiCaprio playing with a
>   dreidel. He wears a severed raven's head as a hat. The wings of the
>   poor animal are shoddily tied to his arms. They barely cover his
>   forearms and looks scrawny. It does not look hygienic. As you approach
>   him he KaKwaa's twice and hands you a scroll and points at the doors.
>
> You look at the scroll, you hear noise outside, the horde has caught
>   up...

[image: Raven's Inception]

Tips:

> http://www.highiqpro.com/solve-matrices-iq-problems
>  Drew inspiration from other places as well, I don't know how official the rules stated on that site are.

Hint:

> In the big grid there are 3 patterns, you need atleast 2 to to find the final answer.
>  **1:** Color of the correct answer; this pattern is observed in the solved state of the smaller puzzles
>  
>  **2:** Something to do with a specific recurring shape in the puzzles;this pattern is observed in the **unsolved** state of the smaller puzzles
>  
>  **3:** Something to do with the same shape as in 2; this pattern is observed in the solved state of the smaller puzzles

Answer (score 3):

**Dubious solution**

I am not fully convinced of my answers to all the subproblems nor of how I've combined them; but I *think* the desired final answer is

> 3.

So, first of all,

> I think the answers to the matrices in the grid are
>  3 1 1
>  4 2 3
>  3 3 -
>  whose colours are -- I'm assuming, as seems to be at least roughly right, that the RGB codes at the top right of the boxes are accurate -- 
>  `#b00 | #009 | #b09
>  #091 | #065 | #0f6
>  #b91 | #06e | ----`

This would mean,

> in view of the XOR relationships between those colours, that we are looking for an answer of #bff for the last one.

And

> the first yields answer 4 whose colour isn't #bff; the second yields answer 2 whose colour is #bff; the third yields either answer 2 or answer 4, one of which has colour #bff and the other not; the fourth yields answer 2 whose colour is #bff.

Which at first sight

> suggests that either 2 or 4 will do ... but then we realise that that is itself a description of the answer to #3, which I therefore propose as final answer.

OP asked about the mid-right puzzle. I wasn't terribly sure about it either, but here for what it's worth was my reasoning, which frankly is probably all wrong, not least because I also allowed myself to be led by chromatic expectations.

> It looks as if the polygon shapes in each row are different, which would mean we want a rectangle in the empty space. It looks as if the total number of borders in each column is even, which would mean the rectangle needs a double border. These two conditions are already enough to require that the answer be #3. I don't think I found any useful regularities in the inner circles. As the paragraph above indicates, I was rationalizing as much as reasoning here, having already decided that I probably needed a #0f6.

Comment: I reached the same conclusions +1

Comment: Good start! However the final conclusion is not what i had in mind; color is not the only pattern in the 'big grid'

Comment: @Adam Does this mean that my solutions of the individual RM problems are the intended ones?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan You did indeed nail them all! :) (If you'd like to share the explanation for middle right, that would be nice, because I felt that one was a bit weak. Just nice to know the thought process)

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer, will update as I go:

**Top left**

> Rule 1 - Imagined as a container, the orientation across each row is always upright -> tilted to the right -> upside down.
>  Rule 2 - Each row contains two solid black squares, a solid black circle, an empty circle, and two empty half-circles.
>
>  The blank must be upside-down, so it can't be #4. We already have two solid black squares so #1 and #2 are out, leaving us with #3 as the answer. This also completes the required quantity of each shape for rule 2.

**Top middle**

> Rule 1: There is always an ascending hill, a descending hill, and rounded hill in each row.
>  Rule 2: Each row contains four unique flowers.
>
>  The blank must contain an ascending hill, ruling out #2. There are already three flowers (purple, yellow, pink) in the middle, ruling out #3 and #4 as one has a duplicate flower colour and one would bring the total flowers to 5. This leaves us with #1 as the answer.

**Top right**

> Rule 1: Imagined as a diamond-shaped grid, each successive "cell" will be taken up by 1 fewer column of black and 1 more column of white.
>  Rule 2: There will always be a circle at the top right with a colour opposite that of its background with a star below and to the left of it.
>
>  Number 4 doesn't have a circle at the top right, so it's out. The only one that has a star below and to the left of the circle is #2, making that my guess at the right answer. (I'm sure there are other rules for the stars but this is the best I could intuit about their placement).

Comment: Nice explanations! Top right is not quite correct.  Top right: Rule 2 is coincidental. I think rule 1 is correct, though I don't understand the wording fully.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a closer look then. Is there a defined rule for where the diamonds/circles go then? For rule 1, basically rotate the square 45 degrees to the right and imagine it's "wiping" from left to right, that makes it easier to picture the diamonds and circles as being in rows and columns.

Comment: Yes, that is a correct, wiping and rows/columns is a good train of thought. The diamonds/circles do have the same movement rule, the rule leaves them freedom where they can go in the grid, which gives the puzzle some noise which may be hard to filter out.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention that I noticed is that each cell also has one fewer white diamond in it: the first has 7, then 6, then 5, then 4, then 3, then 2, then 1, then none. I haven't been able to determine a solid pattern for the others.

Answer (score 0):

Very partial answer

After trying to solve each matrix from the big matrix

All I know for sure (at least for me) is

**The top middle (flower):**
The pattern for each row is

> have 4 distinct flowers
>  have a mound in the middle and symmetrical hills at the side
>  Leading me to answer 1 (Similar answer to Gareth's answer)

**The bottom middle (circle and arrows):** The pattern is

> the second box is the "instruction"
>  first row's instruction was to move BOTH right half left, and the left half right
>  thus this produces the weird inverted circles
>
>  second row's instruction was to delete (indicated by the whiteout) the bottom figure
>  thus left with only the top figure
>
>  following the third's instruction, join the top separated circle
>  Hence leading to the answer 1

**The middle right (circles in shapes):** The pattern is

> Each row has a circle, hexagon and rectangle
>  left and right columns always enclose same type of circles
>
>
>  Since third row's left box contains a quarter in a hexagon and this row has no rectangles
>  We reach the answer 4

Comment: The two bottom ones are not quite on the right track. Bottom middle: you are correct that the 4 corners are objects and the middle ones are operators. The whiteout is a removal indeed, a mini clue; the removal operator could've been left out of the puzzle, i could've just had a blank middle. But i introduced a specific 'removal operator' into the puzzle; why? it's a hint to what is going on to get the final piece