# Find the ? in this logic test

Tags: logical-deduction

> What is the ? in the figure below?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Two copies of shapes in every row, overlapping red and yellow becomes blue

_

> [image]

Comment: Don't know if this is allowed, but my Ravens matrix puzzle is still up for grabs https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53317/ravens-inception Graham came close though

Comment: Is it generally frowned upon to say "Great, I came to the same solution!"? I am still very new to puzzle solving and I did not yet have the chance to be the first to solve a puzzle